# ole32.dll DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mono, ubuntu-12.04, excel-interop

Is there any way to use Excel / Office libraries in Ubuntu?

I've developed a C# program that glues together an Excel spreadsheet and some VB macros. It uses the following.

Excel and Office libraries: Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll and Office.dll. It works perfectly fine in Windows but I can't manage to get it running on Ubuntu using Mono 3.2.

When I try to execute it (after adding the libraries that I explicitly imported using gacutil -l XXXX.dll)
the output is the following:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: ole32.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.__ComObject:CoCreateInstance (System.Guid,intptr,uint,System.Guid,intptr&)
  at System.__ComObject.Initialize (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.__ComObject:Initialize (System.Type)
  at Mono.Interop.ComInteropProxy.CreateProxy (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.CreateClientProxyForComInterop (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateProxyForType (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProgram.Program.joinMacroAndExcel () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProgram.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any help or direction would be highly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Josh

Comment: No. Is that the reason? Is needed to have it installed? Is not possible to generate a xlsx  file using only the libraries? In my development laptop I have one (Windows with Office), but not in the ubuntu future server.

Comment: [In this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726731/wine-and-office-tools) I'm trying other way to make the same but using Wine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel / Office integration libraries require Office to already be installed to run - just copying the PIAs (e.g. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll) is insufficient, as they are to act as the bridge to the COM layer exposed by Excel et al. Without the COM layer, there's nothign to perform the work you're asking of it.

Comment: EPPlus uses OLE32.dll to access compound documents, and this will throw a DllNotFoundException in mono. I have cut the support for compound documents to get it running on linux.

Comment: Did you have to rebuild the EPPlus source to remove compound document support?